# How to delete Sqlite Database in Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, ionic-native

I am using the sqlite plugin in my Ionic App
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

```
    databaseName = 'offline.db';
    destoryDatabase(){
    this.sqlite.deleteDatabase({ name: this.databaseName, location: 'default'});
  }
```

I tried this code it throwing an error. destroyDatabase does not exist. But the function does exists maybe the code might be wrong. Please Help.[image]

Comment: According to the error message, this is not a SQLite error.

Comment: can you add more code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wm764rsu/ please check this may hope it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check your code carefully, because:
In the code it says: "destoryDatabase(){" .
It may be because you didn't close the "}" and also the name is wrong.

But you wrote that the function "destroyDatabase" exists.
As you can see, they're not the same at least in typo.

Check that and please add more code.