# cordova run android takes "wrong" database

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-studio, emulation, android-x86

Hello fellow ionic developer,

I use visual studio code (VSC) to develop an ionic 4 application.

Situation:
Usually I emulate an API 19 Android Phone but this has to be builded everytime `ionic cordova run android` and I can not get it running with the -livereload flag (this takes a lot of time for even little changes). That is when I tried run the app with the cordova plugin for VSC to get a live emulator for debugging and working on my app.

Problemcontext:
I added a database for local storage of patient information. Therefore, I added a seed which provides some patient data and a user. The userlogin works like a charm, during the login I immediatly load all patients for the user. And this is were the problem is:

Apparently, the underlying database / seed is in some old state since I just changed the user values and I can not login with the new seed values.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: a statement error callback did not return false: Failed to import SQL; message=sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: table patient has 14 columns but 27 values were supplied
```

This is the error that brought me here.

So my question is:

**Is there an opportunity to rake/prebuild/... the seed file or where is the seed file located (for using the VSC emulator, since it works on the android studio emulator but also not on the physical device) for the emulator so I can delete or redesign it.**

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Android on emulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 8100,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "ionicLiveReload": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
//DELETE FOR DEPLOY

      this.deleteDatabase("databasename.db");

deleteDatabase(databasename: string)
  {
    try{
      this.sqlite.deleteDatabase(
        {
          name: databasename,
           location: 'default'
          }
      )
    }


    catch(error){
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

You should delete the current database and just populate the database again with the new seed.sql

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033237/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-in-ionic3

Comment: better uninstall the application with `adb`, whenever the schema changes.